# How to use whereNot in laravel scout

Tags: elasticsearch, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-scout

I want to use `whereNot` in laravel scout search but it is not working. although `where` clause is working fine

```
Address::search("{$address->suburb}")->whereNot('id',$address->id)->get();
```

How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do Full Text Search in AES. Read the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html).

Laravel Scout comes with `Algolia` and `MeiliSearch` drivers but if you are writting your own driver for `ElasticSearch`, [this link](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/basemkhirat/elasticsearch) will help you in every aspect including `WhereNot` and all other clauses.

```
ES::type("my_type")->whereNot("status", "published")->get();

# or

ES::type("my_type")->whereNot("status", "=", "published")->get();
```